# Javascript Replace "," with ", "

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace all commas with a comma and a space.

This is what I have tried:

```
all_boxes_values = all_boxes_values.replace(",", ", ");

// and...

all_boxes_values = all_boxes_values.replace(/,\\/g, ', *');
```

I tried the top one first but realised it only replaced one instance of the comma, so I tried the bottom one (from a previous S.O question) but cannot get it to work. There is a possibility that the string may not contain any commas in the first place.

Any ideas?

**UPDATED**

This is the function. I have added one of the below answers to this and it still doesn't work. I now get a console error: TypeError: Object A A Gill has no method 'replace'.

```
$('.name_boxes').live('click', function() {
    var all_boxes = $('.name_boxes');
    var all_boxes_values = []
    for (var i = 0; i < all_boxes.length; i++) {
        if (all_boxes[i].checked) {
            all_boxes_values.push(all_boxes[i].value)
        }
    }
all_boxes_values = all_boxes_values.replace(/,/g,", ");
alert(all_boxes_values);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't have the last two backslashes in your regular expression, and there is no reason for the `*`. The following works.

```
all_boxes_values = all_boxes_values.replace(/,/g,", ");
```

Comment: +1 you beat me to it, this answer is the easiest for me to understand, and the one my thought process brought me to.

Comment: There is no need to escape the comma in a regular expression; it's not a metacharacter. (That said I wouldn't downvote for something like that; it won't hurt to quote the comma.)

Comment: @Pointy I removed it. Thank you.

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: I've just tried using your answer but it didn't seem to work. I'm not saying your answer doesn't work, but my function won't accept it :) I've just updated my question with my function

Comment: [My answer is correct](http://jsfiddle.net/mdQUr/) if `all_boxes_values` was a string, but it's an array. The problem presented in your question initially seemed to be related to a string. You need to perform the replacement on each string (`all_boxes[i]`) in your `for` loop instead.

Comment: Thanks, I have rectified this problem and your original answer worked a treat.

Answer (score 2):

```
all_boxes_values = all_boxes_values.split(',').join(', ');
```

Comment: @James imagine you're on the top of a snowy mountain holding a snowboard in your hand. You start WALKING down the mountain. Eventually you'll reach the bottom - but it just doesn't feel right, does it ?

Answer (score 1):

Kristian Antonsen's answer is the best answer to your original question. Although according to your code if you change it to look like this it will work. You are trying to run replace on an array, and by moving where and to what you preform the replace it should fix that error that you are receiving.
`$('.name_boxes').live('click', function() {
    var all_boxes = $('.name_boxes');
    var all_boxes_values = []
    for (var i = 0; i < all_boxes.length; i++) {
        if (all_boxes[i].checked) {
            all_boxes_values.push(all_boxes[i].value.replace(/,/g,", "));
        }
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you wanted this:

```
all_boxes_values = all_boxes_values.replace(/, */g, ', ');
```